# Best practice for 'if' statements that exceed the 10 line continuation limit in Visual Basic 6.0

Tags: if-statement, vb6, limit, continuations

Example:

```
If condition or _
   condition or _
   condition or _
   condition or _
   condition or _
   condition or _
   condition or _
   condition or _
   condition or _
   condition or Then
    Do something
End If
```

Say I have more than these 10 conditions I need to evaluate... Is there a better way than just nesting multiple sets of these `if` statements?

Comment: You can also put more than one condition on a line but that might hurt readability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an option -- do one test at a time, tracking the final result in a boolean.  When you're all done, just test the boolean.

```
Dim A As Long
Dim B As Long
Dim C As Long
Dim D As Long

Dim Result As Boolean

Result = True
Result = Result And (A > 10)
Result = Result And (B > 10)
Result = Result And (C > 10)
Result = Result And (D > 10)

If Result Then
    ' Do "something" here...
End If
```

If any of A, B, C, or D is less than 10, `Result` will flip to `False` and stay that way from then on.  It will only be `True` if all of the tests pass.

Comment: that's pretty elegant, I like that. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You could use Case statements. It's a little bit cleaner than `if`s: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy37t14y%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: hmmm that would require putting the "do something" function between each of them. or updating a flag for each of them. seems like more code than nested ifs in the long run.

Comment: @TonyRaymond It depends on what the conditions are. If you are checking whether an expression matches a set of values, `Select Case` is perfect. For instance to check whether variable `a` has one of a set of values do this `Select Case a: Case 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10: do something`

Comment: The link is (effectively) broken: *"Visual Studio 2005 Retired documentation"*

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim Result as boolean
result = false
If condition1 Then result = true
ElseIf condition2 Then result = true
ElseIf condition3 Then result = true
ElseIf condition4 Then result = true

If result Then debug.print "Success"
```

If you wanted to use a select statement where conditions are not the same then use:

```
Select Case True
    Case A=5,b=10,c="my answer",d=11
      ....
End Select
```